# Why is $dr/dt= -V$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

In the solution, it says we have $dr/dt= -V$ (polar coordinates)
How? I can't see how this can be possible, we know that $r(t)=V/\omega(t)$, and that's it.

Comment: This is because, the radial distance from the whole is considered as r, and it is *decreasing* at rate V. So the rate of decrement is V. Hence dr/dt=-V.

Comment: How can you prove this statement with vectors?

Comment: Well, I think length of the thread is decreasing with rate V and length is the magnitude of vector r is the only explanation I had. I could not find a better explanation than this. If somebody else can explain the same point more mathematically by using vectors, please help.

Comment: the string is being pulled down at speed $V$. that same string is what connects the mass to the ring. The ring doesn't move. In 1 second, the vertical component of the string is extended by $V$ meters. Therefore, the length of string between the ring and mass must decrease by $V$ meters. Thus, the radius of the mass decreases at the same speed because it is connected to the string being pulled. So dr/dt=-V

Comment: this is not a prove with vectors thing, it is a look at the picture thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question defines $V$ as the rate at which the string is pulled downward through the ring and consequently the rate at the which the radius changes, $-dr/dt$ (negative as the radius is decreasing with time - the fixed length of string is being pulled down).

This $V$ is different from $\underline{\mathbf{v}}$, the velocity vector of the mass, given by $\underline{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{d\underline{\mathbf{r}}}{dt}$ where $\underline{\mathbf{r}}$ is the position vector (independent of the coordinate system you choose). This is the quantity you rightly define in your second statement, $r(t)=\frac{|\underline{\mathbf{v}}|}{\omega(t)}$.

Overall, you need to be careful between what are scalar quantities ($V$, $r$ and $dr/dt$) and what are vector quantities ($\underline{\mathbf{v}}$ and $\underline{\mathbf{r}}$). Sometimes the vectors will only be bold which can make it difficult to distinguish but the context is key, it is rare to find an error in a textbook as much as we may sometimes wish it so. The devil is in the detail!

Answer (score 1):

$r(t)=r(0)-Vt.$ $V$ is *not* the tangential speed (indeed it's the radial speed).

Comment: This seems better suited as a comment.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I don't think so. It appears to answer the question to me.